# Java method implicitly called by println ....why?

Tags: java, string

I have a question about why the toString() method is implicitly called when the main method calls the printPersonPrinting() method.

```
public class PersonPrinting {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public PersonPrinting(String aName, int anAge) {
        name = aName;
        age = anAge;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + age;
    }

    public void printPersonPrinting() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        PersonPrinting p = new PersonPrinting("Dan",10);
        //printPersonPrinting is called, but toString isn't. 
       //But the output is formatted by toString method.
        p.printPersonPrinting();
    }
}
```

The output of this code is --> Dan 10

Thanks!!

Comment: Notice, that your method `toString` is overriding `Object.toString` which is not immediately clear because your code is lacking the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: How else could it print the object? What do you think it could do instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just the way Java works. By default, `System.out.println()` calls the `toString()` method on its param object to convert it to its string representation.

If the object's class is not overriding the `toString()` method, you may get as a result something like `className@someHexadecimalNumber`. *(which is  the result of the default implementation of the `toString()` method in the `Object` class)*

Answer (score 8):

Because `System.out.println(this);` invokes

```
String.valueOf(this)
```

which in turn calls

```
this.toString()
```

It's basically `System.out.println(this.toString());`.

[`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) so you can see [`PrintStream.println(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-) which says (in part)

> This method calls at first `String.valueOf(x)` to get the printed object's string value, then behaves as though it invokes [`print(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-java.lang.String-) and then [`println()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println--).

Answer (score 2):

> Java method implicitly called ... why?

One answer is (basically) that that is the way that `println(Object)` is specified to work.

Another answer is that that is the best (simple) design alternative.  Consider:

- `println(Object)` is supposed to output a text rendering of the object
- there are two alternatives:

  - use a generic mechanism to render the object
  - use a rendering method (like `toString()`)
- considering the "generic mechanism", how would it decide what fields of the object to render, and how to render them?  Unless the programmer can somehow tailor rendering, it is impossible for a generic mechanism to "get it right".  And the tailoring, is liable to be *more complicated* than writing a `toString()` method.
- considering the `toString()` approach, the method can be overridden to render the object as the programmer wants ... or not.

Now admittedly, a simple `toString()` method is often not sufficiently flexible, but that can be addressed in a variety of ways; e.g.

- use `PrintWriter.format(...)` to do the formatting / writing, or
- use a formatter that generates a String and `PrintWriter.print(String)`.

(For situations where you need to render and output large amounts of text, you need to use a different approach; i.e. not a `PrintWriter`. That is a different topic.)